# Part of a cow that carries waste

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call the pouch like thing that carries waste material in a cow's stomach? Is it tripe? According to my knowledge tripe is the lining of any stomach chamber in a cow. So what exactly is the name of that bag which has dung and comes out full of waste when a cow is slaughtered.

Comment: Tripe is the *stomach* lining (that's an early part of the digestive process, but I think cows have several stomachs dealing with different phases of the cellulose breakdown). You wouldn't call it "waste" until right at the end of the alimentary canal - which is either the large intestine or the cecum, I think. You could look that up, though. I expect cows have a small intestine before the large intestine, like humans, but maybe not

Comment: I looked up a lot , couldn't find it. If know where, let me know

Comment: Are you talking about the caecum/cecum? It's the large area where the small and large intestine meet.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's name is. That's what i need to know. It's a big fleshy bag that carries the things a cow eats, in a kind of waste. I've seen anatomy but it says there are 4 chambers in stomach. Now which one is that bag kind of thing i don't know

Comment: There are lots of different "bags" in the cow - it's basically just a huge multi-chamber fermentation vessel on legs, with different parts of the digestive process happening all the way through several "stomachs" *and* the large & small intestine (and maybe the caecum - I've never known what that bit does). But what they contain isn't "waste" until it gets right up to the rectum.

Comment: The large intestine is where food waste is stored until it is expelled. *6. [The large intestine is the final step of the digestive process](https://proearthanimalhealth.com/how-does-the-digestive-system-work-in-a-cow-understanding-the-ruminant-digestive-system/#Components%20of%20the%20Ruminant%20Digestive%20System). It absorbs remaining water and contains bacteria microbes that finish digestion and produce vitamins the animal needs to grow and remain healthy. Its last job is to eliminate any undigested and unabsorbed food from the system in the form of waste.*

Comment: Since this is the english language learners' SE, and not the biology or english SE, I feel like I ought to mention: This is absolutely not a word that the average english-speaker would be expected to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[large intestine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_intestine)** is where faeces is defecated, but the OP mentioned a "pouch thing”, which I think is: [emphasis in bold mine]

> **The Caecum**

> This part of the intestinal system is a connection between the end of the small intestine (ileum) and the start of the large intestine. The ileocaecal valve separates the caecum and the ileum. The caecum is considered to be the start of the large intestine.
> **In herbivores, such as cattle, the caecum is greatly enlarged and serves as a storage organ that permits bacteria and other microbes time to further digest cellulose.** In carnivores, including humans, the caecum is relatively unimportant in function.

Source: [Vet in Training](http://vetstudentresearch.blogspot.com/2015/05/digestive-physiology-and-anatomy-of-cows.html)

Answer (score 1):

The largest stomach compartment of a cow is the **rumen**.

The parts of digestive track are mouth, esophagus, the four-compartment stomach and intestines.
source: [The ruminant digestive system](https://extension.umn.edu/dairy-nutrition/ruminant-digestive-system#stomach-compartments-1000460)

Stomach includes :

- The rumen (paunch)
- The reticulum (“honeycomb”)
- The omasum (“manyplies”)
- The abomasum (“true stomach”)